# Table View not working with custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using storyboard, but my custom cell is inside a xib. The table is there, but no cell appears. My code:

OurTeamCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OurTeamCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LabelNome;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LabelOcupacao;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageFoto;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *fundoCellImage;


@end
```

OurTeamCell.m

```
#import "OurTeamCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation OurTeamCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }

    self.fundoCellImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

OurTeam.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OurTeam : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewTeam;

@end
```

OurTeam.m

```
#import "OurTeam.h"
#import "OurTeamCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE

@interface OurTeam ()

@end

@implementation OurTeam{

    NSMutableDictionary *listaTeam;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableViewTeam.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableViewTeam.opaque = NO;
    self.tableViewTeam.backgroundView = nil;

    self.tableViewTeam.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    NSMutableArray *listaNomes = [NSMutableArray new];

    [listaNomes addObject:@"TESTE"];

    [listaTeam setObject:listaNomes forKey:@"nomes"];

    if (UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()) {

        self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fundo~ipad.png"]];

    } else {

        if (isiPhone5)
        {

            self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fundo4inch.png"]];
        }
        else
        {

            self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fundo.png"]];
        }
    }
}

-(int) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

-(int) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [listaTeam count];
}

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef imgRef = [image CGImage];
    CGImageRef maskRef = [maskImage CGImage];
    CGImageRef actualMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);
    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imgRef, actualMask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    OurTeamCell *cell = (OurTeamCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OurTeamCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = [UIView new];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [UIView new];

    cell.LabelNome.text = [[listaTeam objectForKey:@"nomes"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

@end
```

EDIT:

This is how the table view appears:
[image: screen]

Comment: Is listaTeam empty?  That seems to be controlling the count.  It looks like everything else is in order.

Comment: [listaNomes addObject:@"TESTE"];

[listaTeam setObject:listaNomes forKey:@"nomes"];

This is what I did until I have the right list, it's there in the OurTeam.m

Comment: Oh yes, it is a dictionary.  You may need to do the count of "nomes" [[listaTeam objectForKey:@"nomes"] count].

Comment: @0xFADE I did it, but nothing changed

Comment: You would then need to see if there is something wrong with the cell.  The easiest way would be to use a generic table view cell and set it's text with cell.textLabel.text.  There could be some part of a view that is covering the text you want to show.

Comment: @0xFADE I tested with default cell, but, nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never created the listaTeam dictionary. You can't use setObject:forKey: until you alloc init the dictionary (or use one of the other dictionary creation methods). You also do need to change what you're returning in numberOfRowsInSection to what 0xFADE said in his comment.

```
listaTeam = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[listaTeam setObject:listaNomes forKey:@"nomes"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

`[self.tableViewTeam reloadData];`

As the last line of code in the `-viewDidLoad` method.

You need to tell the table view that your data has updated... by calling the `-reloadData` method.

**[EDIT]**

As 0xFADE stated in the OP comments you also need to return the count of nomes `[[listaTeam objectForKey:@"nomes"] count]` in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method too.

Comment: Very likely the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding this to `-(void)viewDidLoad` in `OurTeam.m`

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[OurTeamCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];
```

Comment: This won't solve his problem. However it would be more useful for him to use the `registerNib` method as an alternative to this one since his cell is in a nib.